# Issues with Relink of Item when Archiving an item

Tags: sitecore-client, link-database

When I try to relink an Item on archive to another item I get the following error

```
Job started: Relink|System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase.GetItem(String path)
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.LayoutField.Relink(ItemLink itemLink, Item newLink)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.BreakingLinks.BreakingLinksForm.Relink.RelinkLink(Item sourceItem, ItemLink itemLink)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.BreakingLinks.BreakingLinksForm.Relink.RelinkItemLinks(LinkDatabase linkDatabase, Item targetItem, Boolean relinkCloneLinks)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.BreakingLinks.BreakingLinksForm.Relink.RelinkItemLinks(LinkDatabase linkDatabase, Item targetItem, Boolean relinkCloneLinks)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.BreakingLinks.BreakingLinksForm.Relink.RelinkItemLinks(LinkDatabase linkDatabase, Item targetItem, Boolean relinkCloneLinks)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.BreakingLinks.BreakingLinksForm.Relink.RelinkItems()|Job ended: Relink (units processed: 1)
```

Anyone had this issue and know how to resolve this? We are using Sitecore 9.3

Tried rebuilding link databases with no luck.

Comment: can you add your code which is doing relink ?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding link database from Control Panel first?

Comment: is not custom code, its builtin function

Comment: yes, I did do rebuild link database

Comment: Most likely the xml in the rendering field of the layout section of the itemlink is corrupted.